# Disable Ghostery add-on intro page in Selenium Firefox profile - Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am using [Ghosetry](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ghostery/) add-on in my Selenium Firefox profile. Firefox is opening with Ghostry add-on but I have two issues with that.

1. Every time I invoke Selenium-Firefox, it is going to intro page `https://extension.ghostery.com/intro#start`. How can I disable that?
2. By default Ghostery add-on is not stopping/blocking all the trackers. How can I block all the trackers by default?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
from randomAttibute_firefox import RandomAttributes
firefoxProfile = FirefoxProfile()
ghostery_addon="/Users/Desktop/ghostery.xpi"
firefoxProfile.add_extension(ghostery_addon)
firefoxProfile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefoxProfile)
driver.get("https://ipleak.net/")
```

I don't want to go intro page of Ghostery, every time I invoke a browser. In addition, I need to block/disable all the trackers by default. I searched in Google but can't find any settings to customize Ghostery add-on.

Comment: While this question happens to be about the instance of Firefox that is run on your Selenium profile, the actual questions are about the normal operation of Firefox (how to control Ghostery and disable tracking). These are general computing questions. Thus, in my opinion, this would be more appropriate on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Comment: @Makyen Thanks for your suggestion, I asked the same question in  Super User.